# How to make a table of images

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table with three pictures in a row and all of them the same size.  My pictures in the files are not all the same size or even facing upright.  Is there a way to make every picture the same width, height, transformation, and in line?  Here is my code so far.  Also, for some reason it only styles the first img different from the rest.  Thank you!

CSS

```
      #pics {
        margin-top: 8%;
      }

      #pics td {
        height: 100px;
        padding-top: .5em;
        padding-bottom: 5em;
      }

      #pics img {
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-right: 5%;
        height: 90%;
        border: 5px #72dbd4 solid;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        display: inline;
      }

      #cliffPano {
        width: 90%;
      }
```

HTML

```
      <table id="pics">
        <tr>
          <td><img src="blogPics/battleship.JPG" /></td>
          <td><img src="blogPics/PHMemorial.JPG" /></td>
          <td><img src="blogPics/roadToHana.JPG" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="blogPics/hawaiiTree.jpg" /></td>
          <td><img src="blogPics/hawaiiOcean.JPG" /></td>
          <td><img src="blogPics/planeHawaii.JPG" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><img id="cliffPano" style="transform: rotate(0deg);"src="blogPics/cliffPano.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: There is no good way to resize the pictures (though rotating them isn't too hard). You'll want to make them the right size yourself: imagine all the CPU cycles the world would waste (not to mention a slower website) if you made users do the work every time in their browser!

Answer (score 0):

To make all the images the same size, you can set their specific pixel values in your CSS:

```
#pics img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    ...
}
```

The CSS transform is probably not going to do what you want. I'd suggest that you rotate all the image files themselves first.

Answer (score 0):

One useful way would be you to learn a bit of php. With it you can create equal thumb image previews. Here is the exact php function link ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

That belongs to the php GD and image functions lib that it is the one more likely available. That way you can truly fix that